# How to read array object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got this array objects to be read:

[image]

These was my sample codes:

```
$scope.obj_qst_local_study_main = tbl_qst_local_study_main.all();
$scope.quesion_id_allocated = $scope.obj_qst_local_study_main[0];
$timeout(function(){
    console.log('----------all objects----------');
    console.log($scope.obj_qst_local_study_main);
    console.log('-----------one object-----------');
    console.log($scope.quesion_id_allocated);
},200);
```

When I used:

```
$scope.obj_qst_local_study_main[0];
```

The result was: `undefined`

---

My angularjs services:

```
.service('tbl_qst_local_study_main', function($cordovaSQLite, DATABASE_LOCAL_NAME){
            var self = this;
            var qst_local_study_main_array = [];
            self.all = function() {
              var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: DATABASE_LOCAL_NAME,location:'default'});
                    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM qst_local_study_main")
                            .then(function (res) {
                                console.log('--------Successfully read from qst_local_study_main---------');
                                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                                    qst_local_study_main_array.push(res.rows.item(i));
                                }
                            },
                                function (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                });
                    return qst_local_study_main_array;
            };
        })
```

Comment: You need to show some code. For exmple, what does `tbl_qst_local_study_main.all();` do?

Comment: So my wild guess is that `tbl_qst_local_study_main.all()` is an async call. so, when you assign the first item in the second line the call has not finished.

Comment: A wild *asynchronous function that returns a value* appears.

Comment: So what I need to do then @SebastianSebald ?

Comment: put $scope.quesion_id_allocated = $scope.obj_qst_local_study_main[0]; inside the $timeout

Comment: see what is the result

Comment: @Araz inside the timeout?  I'm thinking maybe that's not going to help so much

Comment: try see whats happening ... you have one $timeout function

Comment: @araz you mean promise, not timeout, correct?

Comment: @Araz still undefined

Comment: the correct way is promis but see when you console log the item in timeout it gives you the result ... so you need to assign scope [0] item when its assigned in the $timeout

Comment: have you used then function like tbl_qst_local_study_main.all().then(function(youData){

Comment: console.log yourData in then function

Comment: The data was there... I just need to read back the object

Comment: yourData shows the result?

Comment: as the picture in my question @Araz

Comment: so you can assign $scope variable in then function like: $scope.something = yourData[0]

Comment: I need to separate my services with my controller. I just return the value from services. I tried your code `$scope.something = yourData[0]` but still give the result `undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your service should return a `Promise`. This is a super common case, because (don't be offended please) people do not understand how `Promises` work.

Please search the internet for an article, like this one: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

*tl;dr* Your service should return a `Promise`. In your case `$cordovaSQLite.execute` Then you can correctly handle the response by chaining `then`s. You also do not need the timeout. Using a timeout is super bad here!

```
tbl_qst_local_study_main.all()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
```

Comment: `$timeout` was super bad?Oh no..so I need to use `promise`..I need to try first.

Comment: Yes, because you can not predict how long you async call needs. Your code would throw/return nothing if the call needs more than 200ms. :-(

Comment: Can you show me? I do not know how to use `promise`

Comment: Added an example. But please go and read an article about `Promises`. Not going to write you your software ;-)

Comment: Ok..I got it. Then I should remove all timeout I used to get the returned value